# Equivalence in the definitions of abelian variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

In the algebraic setting, an abelian variety $ X $ of dimension $ n $ over $ \mathbb{C} $ is defined as follows - $ X $ is a connected, projective algebraic group of dimension $ n $ over $ \mathbb{C} $. (To be clear, I'm thinking of this as a scheme here.)

In the complex geometry setting, an abelian variety of dimension $ n $ is a compact complex torus of dimension $ n $ (a quotient of $ \mathbb{C}^n $ by a rank $ 2n $ lattice) which is also projective.

Definition two clearly implies definition one. Why does definition one imply definition two, in other words why is an algebraic abelian variety automatically a complex torus?

The motivation for asking this question is that I know that most compact complex tori are not projective. So I want to know the 'reverse' in some sense.

Comment: This is because $X$ is its own Albanese variety $H^0(X,\Omega^1)^\vee/H_1(X,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: If you don't know what 'Albanese variety' means you might also want to take a look at say Section 2 of Milne's notes on abelian varieties. It starts with an abelian variety (in the algebraic sense) over $\mathbb{C}$, and uses some basic Lie theory tools to prove that the complexification is in fact a torus in the topological sense.

Comment: Intuitively the group is abelian because $g\to g a g^{-1}$ is an holomorphic map $G\to End(Lie(G))\subset \Bbb{C}^m$ but there is no nonconstant holomorphic map from a compact manifold to $\Bbb{C}^m$ (maximum modulus)

Comment: @Jeroen van der Meer thank you. I indeed did not know about the Albanese. This cleared things up.

Comment: @AlexYoucis - You should explain in detail how you construct the quotient Albanese variety.

Answer (score -5):

**Question:** "Definition two clearly implies definition one. Why does definition one imply definition two, in other words why is an algebraic abelian variety automatically a complex torus?"

**Answer:** In the case of dimension $1$ you find an "elementary introduction" in Hartshornes book "Algebraic geometry", Chapter IV.4. You should try to read this book before trying to understand higher dimensional abelian varieties. When you have understood this you could continue to read the books of Mumford and Milne.
There is also the following book(s):

(1) Mumford, David (2008) [1970], Abelian varieties, Tata Institute of Fundamental Research Studies in Mathematics, 5, Providence.

(2) Mumford, "Geometric invariant theory".

In (2) he defines an abelian scheme $G/S$ ($S$ a   noetherian scheme) to be

(*) a group scheme $G$ with $\pi:G \rightarrow S$ smooth, proper and with connected geometric fibers. In Corr 6.5 in (2) he proves that $G$ is a commutative group scheme meaning for any scheme $T/S$ it follows $G(T):=Mor_S(T,G)$ is an abelian group.

Hence if your "quotient" $\pi: A:=\mathbb{C}^n/\Gamma \rightarrow Spec(\mathbb{C})$ satisfies $(*)$ it follows $A$ is a commutative group scheme over $\mathbb{C}$ in the above sense.

Taking "quotients" in algebraic geometry is a delicate topic and the Mumford book is a good place to read about this.

**Note:** The scheme $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}:=Spec(\mathbb{C}[x_1,..,x_n]):=Spec(R)$ is an affine scheme and the group $\Gamma \cong \mathbb{Z}^{2n}$ is a group acting on $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$. You cannot simply construct the "quotient" using the Spec of the invariant ring $Spec(R^{\Gamma})$ since $Spec(R^{\Gamma})$ is an affine scheme. The quotient $A$ is a projective scheme.

There is a section on the Picard scheme in the book Bosch/Raynaud/Lutkebohmert "Neron models" that may be of interest: The Albanese variety is dual to the Picard variety.

Comment: I do know the Weierstrass doubly periodic function and so I think I understand the n=1 case very well and I've also read Hartshorne. So I'm sorry, but this answer does not really help.

Comment: @Corile- when you ask this type of question you should include some information on what you know and have read. Then people on this site can give references. Elliptic curves and abelian varieties is an "advanced" topic and the Hartshorne book is a good place to start.

Comment: I saw your edit. That also doesn't answer my question as I'm starting with the algebraic definition (and not a torus). But I'll have a look at the references, thanks.

Comment: @Corile - The above remark on the Albanese variety speaks of "quotients" and the Mumford book is about thie topic: How to construct quotients in algebraic geometry

Comment: @Corile - the book "Neron models" is a good book. You need to know algebraic geometry at the level of Hartshorne.